# Making a video from arbitrary named files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have image files from a webcam, they are named in the format: 2018-02-06-16-40-05.jpg
Is it possible to make a video out of these images without having to rename them in a format similar to image%04d.jpg, etc.

Comment: Which platform / operating system you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The glob is bash style and `*` stands for any number of characters.

Or you can use:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output.mkv
```

Both solutions are sorting the images by name ascending order. Should be fine, if you have filenames with date and time.

More informations here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Comment: Note: Not available on Windows

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks, you're right. Should have asked before ;)

Comment: good answer,  I omitted some minor other things not related to ffmpeg in the original question, but related to my needs, I'll address them on my own.